# Dialog box not getting dismissed in android

Tags: android, dialog

in my app when i touch an edit box i am opening an dialog box which consists of a 3 Character sequence as Full format, year format and cancel. When i select the one among them another dialog box gets opened.

When the second dialog box gets opened i want the first dialog box to be either dismissed or cancelled automatically, but it is not happening..... Following is the part of my code

```
 private OnTouchListener bdListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
     {
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
          {
              DOBalert();
              return isexists;
          }
          private void DOBalert()
          {
            Builder DOBbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RestingSpotAdd.this);
            DOBbuilder.setTitle("Date of Birth");
            final CharSequence[] items = {"YearFormat", "FullFormat","Cancel"};
            DOBbuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) 
               {
                  int i = item;
                  if(i==0)
                  {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        yearFormat();
                  }
                  else if(i==1)
                  { 
                      dialog.cancel();
                      fullFormat();
                  }
                  else if(i==2)
                  {
                      cancel();  
                  }
               }
               public void yearFormat()
               {
                   showDialog(YEARSELECTOR_ID);
               }
               public void fullFormat()
               {
                   showDialog(DATEYEARMONTHSELECTOR_ID);
               }
         });
         AlertDialog DOBalert = DOBbuilder.create();
         DOBalert.show();
       }
     };
```

Please help me friends......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `onTouchListener` instead of `onClickListener`?

The problem is that when you click an item in your list dialog, the touch event of the dialog  is also fired causing it to be shown again.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
  dialog.dismiss();
```